# How do I create an exposed filter for a localized taxonomy term?

Tags: views, i18n-l10n

How do I create an exposed filter for a localized taxonomy term? My vocabulary is set to 'Localize' and I'm able to create a translation for each term in this vocabulary. In my View, however, I can't add a localized taxonomy term to the filter. This is an exposed filter and I'd like the selection items to show up in the user's language.

How do I display localized taxonomy terms in a filter?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you need to install i18nviews module
and then use one of these:

- Content: Has taxonomy term (translated)
- Content: Has taxonomy terms (with depth, translated)

instead of regular filters